# How to re-bind docker volume after removing data-only container?

Tags: docker

Following the example in the official guide on [Managing Data in Containers](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/), suppose there is a data-only container created via

```
docker create -v /data --name data-container image /bin/true
```

Also suppose there is at least one running consumer container, using the volume created in the data-only container:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from data-container --name consumer-container image
```

Now consider deletion of the data-container with the `-v` switch while the consumer is still running:

```
docker rm -v data-container
```

I understand [the docs](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) say that this does not affect the consumer-container, because the volume actually remains available:

> "To delete the volume from disk, you must explicitly call docker rm -v
>   against **the last container with a reference to the volume**."

So, that is comparable to the `unlink()` system call. The data volume remains available, in a "pending" state. With "pending" I mean that this exact volume cannot be bound to other containers anymore by simply using `--volumes-from`. Speaking in terms of the `unlink()` analogy, there is no name anymore by which the data could be accessed.

**My question is:** is there a way to re-create a data-only container based on this pending volume so that it can be included again via `--volumes-from`? Or is such a "pending" volume condemned, in the sense that once the last consumer stops the data will be gone?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to determine the location of the volume on the underlying host with `docker inspect --format="{{.Volumes}}" <Container ID>`.

Whilst the consumer-container is still running, you could possibly, on the host, copy the contents of the volume to another location and create a new data-container based on the contents of that new location.

A downside is that further changes might be written to the original volume in the time between the end of your copy and stopping the consumer-container (which leads to the deletion of the original volume).

It's not ideal then, but it's one way I could see that this might be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. You are saying that we can find the location of the volume. That sounds great. What can we do with it? You did not *explicitly* say that, even with this location in our hands, we can not directly bind this to a fresh data-only container. So just to be sure I am asking: is that currently possible or impossible?

Comment: Ok, this is how I saw it going. You find the actual location of the volume, then you copy it to /data on the host. Once the original container has stopped you then fire up a new data container but this time map the host location to the container location like so: `-v /data:/data` . You should then be able to use `--volumes-from` when you start the new consumer-container. I'll flesh out my answer some more to clarify this (tomorrow ;-)).

Comment: Re-reading your comment I see you're asking about rebinding the volume in its original location, whereas my answer is all about working around the problem by making sure the data is not lost by copying it away before the volume is deleted. I suspect that it's not possible to rebind to the original location (as shown by the `docker inspect`), but I can't give you a definitive answer on that.